# Can I query the available service principle APIs through Graph or PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, service-principal

I am automating the requesting of AAD service principals / applications, or more specifically the APIs, and am trying to pull a list of all the APIs available through the portal, using either Graph or PowerShell.

Specifically, if you go into an application and click on the "API Permissions" tab, you get a list of API collections, then drilling down you get to "Delegated or Application permissions" and finally the APIs.  Any way to walk this tree programmatically would be wonderful!

I am not holding a lot of hope that this list is exposed, but have my fingers crossed somebody can help.

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can query for service principals from the MS Graph API and get what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http.

That gives you a list of all service principals: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-beta.

You can also use the AzureAD PowerShell module's cmdlet `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` to get this data.

Either way you get the data,
you can find delegated permissions under *oauth2Permissions* property.

> The OAuth 2.0 permissions exposed by the associated application. For more information see the oauth2Permissions property definition on the application entity. Not nullable.

Application permissions are found in *appRoles* property.

> The application roles exposed by the associated application. For more information see the appRoles property definition on the application entity. Not nullable.

However, not all appRoles are application permissions.
An appRole has an allowedMemberTypes property:

> Specifies whether this app role definition can be assigned to users and groups by setting to "User", or to other applications (that are accessing this application in daemon service scenarios) by setting to "Application", or to both.

So you want to check for appRoles with "Application" as an allowed member type,
those are application permissions.

Comment: Sorry, I was probably not very clear.  I can query the SP just fine.  I am trying programmatically get a list of all the APIs available, be they Azure, InTune... Application or Delegated.... I want to harvest the complete list so I can build a request form in Service Now to allow users to request a SP and the APIs they need.  I'll then review/approved, create the SP for them, along with the APIs (approved if necessary).

As the APIs will always be changing, I wanted to be able to query for them programmatically so I can update my list periodically.

Hope this helps clarify.